# Space below navbar-fixed-top Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a mysterious space (roughly 25px) between the navbar and the content div. I am using Chrome and 1600x900 screen resolution.  I have looked at other questions with the exact same problem, and I applied the answers given, but the problem persists. I have set the margin bottom of the navbar to 0 and override Bootstrap 3.1.1. 
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <title>Title</title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <script src="js/lib/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
        </head>

        <body>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/title.png"></img></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>     
                        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
                <div class="content"></div>           
        </body>

    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
  padding: 70px 0 0 0;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
/* Top Navigation Bar */
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  min-height: 0;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-header{
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  background: rgb(255, 240, 240);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Change the body padding to..

```
body { 
  padding: 45px 0 0 0;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/u6miPwWKTj

Comment: Hey that worked, hmm, how though? That padding ought to affect top of the body? Im confused. What does that bit of code actually do to 'body'?

Comment: Aah it is the same height as the navbar. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to hardcode the `padding-top` value in your CSS, since it depends on the navbar's height.

I would instead use a JS script for assigning that value dynamically:

```js
function updatePaddingTop() {
    $("body").css({
        "padding-top" : $(".navbar").outerHeight()
    });
}
$(document).ready(() => updatePaddingTop())

var observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
    updatePaddingTop();
}).observe($(".navbar")[0]);
```

The use of `ResizeObserver` is for detecting possible changes in the navbar size and re-apply the above fix.